# How many edits is "too many pending edits"?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I was about to submit an edit on a question, when I got this:

[image: too many pending edits]

I do not remember how many edits I did in the whole day, and how many of them are yet pending. So I would like to know when do we get such error/warning message? Specifically speaking, how many pending edits make up for this warning message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like that are covered in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/295232). It says you can have at most 5 pending suggested edits here, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232) (that Q&A also explains *why* there is a limit). You can see your pending edits [in your profile](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). This is *not* a limit per day; if your edits are approved (or rejected) sooner than that, you can suggest new edits the same day.

Comment: Thank you so much, for editing the title of my question as well as for the answer. I had never explored the other tabs available in the profile page. I must do it one fine day.